# Nextjs14 "Styled-components" to SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, styled-components, csr, next.js14

I added "use client" top of page.tsx file, using 'styled-components' library, and It caused delay (might be 0.2s) when loading the page in browser. I think the delay occurs because styled-component is applied on the client(CSR). Is there a way to respond the page to the client after applying styled-components by SSR in advance?

Do babel still working in nextjs ver14?
styled components is so convenient and amazing library i think, so i want to keep this lib.

Comment: Did you try to implement Next's team [provider](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js#styled-components) for styled-components?